# How to show the errors using react-hook-form and MUI React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I have the following component:

```
const App = () => {
 const formProps = useForm({
      mode: "onBlur",
 });
const { handleSubmit, formState, register, watch, reset } = formProps;
return (
 <FormProvider {...formProps}>
    <DialogComponent content={<CreateRole register={register} />}
  </FormProvider >
)
}
```

CreateRole.jsx:

```
export const CreateRole = ({ register }) => {
  return (
    <Stack direction={"column"} gap={3}>
      <SelectField
        label={"Role Name"}
        name={"roleName"}
        register={register}
        list={data}
        margin="dense"
      />
  );
}
```

SelectField.jsx:

```
export const SelectField = ({ label, name, register, list, ...rest }) => {
  const {
    watch,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm();

  console.log("errors[name]", errors[name]);

  return (
    <TextField
      label={label}
      required
      select
      name={name}
      fullWidth
      value={watch(name)}
      variant="outlined"
      error={!!errors[name]} 
      helperText={errors[name]?.message}  // here I am not able to see the errors. 
      {...rest}
      {...register(name, {
        required: "This field is required.",
      })}
    >
      {list?.map((item, index) => (
        <MenuItem key={index} value={item.value}>
          {item.label}
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
    </TextField>
  );
};
```

Here in the above component I am trying to set the errors, But I am not able to see the error when try to select but I don't select the value. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear what your particular use case is, but if you want to validate the `Select' input value when the popover closes, you can use the combination of the` onClose`callback and the RHF`trigger` method to do the input validation. Here's an example:

```
function Form() {
  const { trigger } = useForm()

  return <TextField SelectProps={{ onClose: () => trigger("fieldName") }}>...</TextField>
}
```

It's worth noting that in your example you're mixing two concepts: the uncontrolled and controlled input RHF APIs: `register` and `watch`. You shouldn't explicitly pass the `value` prop to the `Select` component when using the `register` API.